# Extra column with GridLayout and JScrollPane not showing - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am messing around with Swing and I find that some elements are not appearing in my application.  Most notably the JScrollPane and for some reason there seems to be a grid column between my JTextArea and JButtons.

See the image below:
[image]

My method is as follows:

```
 private void panels(){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Viewing All Program Details");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(15,0,10,10));
        rightPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 5, 5, 10));
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(storeAllString,0,70);
        JScrollPane scrollBarForTextArea=new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        panel.add(textArea);
        frame.add(scrollBarForTextArea);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.getContentPane().add(rightPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.setSize(1000, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        rightPanel.add(saveCloseBtn);
        rightPanel.add(closeButton);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious...

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(storeAllString,0,70);
JScrollPane scrollBarForTextArea=new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
panel.add(textArea);
```

This isn't how you use a `JScrollPane`, essentially what you've done is removed the `textArea` from the `JScrollPane` by adding it to the `panel`.  A component can only reside within a single parent container at a time.

Instead, you should be adding the scroll pane to the `panel`...

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(storeAllString,0,70);
JScrollPane scrollBarForTextArea=new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
panel.add(scrollBarForTextArea);
```

The "extra" column is actually a sympton of the previous problem...

```
panel.add(textArea);
frame.add(scrollBarForTextArea); // This is the "extra" column
frame.getContentPane().add(panel,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.getContentPane().add(rightPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
```

The empty `JScrollPane` is what you are seeing.  With the fixes from before, you only need to do...

```
frame.add(panel);
frame.getContentPane().add(rightPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
```

You should, also, call `setVisible` after you've finished building the UI if possible